# Picker value keeps being reset

Tags: react-native, expo

Some background
I am building an app to place food orders for a restaurant. It has a global cart object that stores what items are in the cart and how many there are.
In my cart screen, I have a flatlist showing all the items in the cart. I have a picker inside each item in a flat list representing the quantity. When I try and change the value it is instantly reset to the original value. When onValueChange is called it correctly processes the change and set the new value, but as soon as it does, somehow the value changes again and is reset back to the previous value.
I have a nearly identical picker that can use one variable stored in the state that works fine, but in this case, it would require an array which I cant incorporate into the flatlist.

I have tried to pass a function call directly to the cart to retrieve the quantity for selectedValue. The information in the cart object is correct it just keeps getting reset by the call from onValueChange.
I have tried storing the data for the flatlist in the state so when the value changes I call setState as some people suggested.
I tried setting the data directly to a call to the cart to get all the data

EDIT:
I set a variable in my constructor that would prohibit the onValueChange from running unless it was physically pressed. I did this by surrounding the picker with a touchable opacity and set the onpress to changing the variable, then once onValueChange ran I would change the variable again. Even though all this the value in displayed in the picker does not change. The value itself does as I have a total price of everything in the cart which shows the change, but for some reason the picker doesnt :(

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.data}
    renderItem={({item}) => 
        //other components
        <Picker
            selectedValue={item.quantity}
            style={{height: 50, width: 85, paddingRight: 10}}
            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
                console.log('val changed called')
                global.cart.setQuantity(item, itemValue)
                this.setState({data: global.cart.getData()})
                console.log('after set q = ' + global.cart.getQuantity(item))
                }
            }
        >
            <Picker.Item label="1" value="1"/>
            <Picker.Item label="2" value="2"/>
            <Picker.Item label="3" value="3"/>
            <Picker.Item label="4" value="4"/>
            <Picker.Item label="5" value="5"/>
            <Picker.Item label="6" value="6"/>
            <Picker.Item label="7" value="7"/>
            <Picker.Item label="8" value="8"/>
            <Picker.Item label="9" value="9"/>
            <Picker.Item label="10" value="10"/>
        </Picker>
    }
/>
```

functions from global.cart

```
setQuantity = (item, num) => {
    let i = this.searchItem(item)
    this.items[i].quantity = num
    console.log("new quantity = " + this.items[i].quantity)
}

getQuantity = (item) => {
    let i = this.searchItem(item)
    return (this.items[i].quantity)
}
```

Expected selectedValue to change as the user selects a number, value is always reset

Answer (score 0):

I believe `global.cart.getData()` returns the same object and the component is not re-rendering. Try:

```js
renderItem={({item, index}) =>
...
onValueChange = {(value) => {
  let newData = [...this.state.data];
  newData[index] = {...newData[index], quantity:value};
  this.setState({data: newData});
}}
```

Comment: I can confirm with multiple console.log's that it returns the correct object and re-renders, but then its as if the field is set again triggering a reset of the value

Comment: I can't see why you can't incorporate an array in flatlist. The code I've shown you works as my understanding of you question. Also, it is better to use component state to manage its state than keep calling functions from another object, the former is just way easier to understand.